# How to replicate in React Native - border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anyone help me how to replicate `border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;` in React Native so I have egg-like object shape? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with _replicate_ ? Can you add some details to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Egg = () => {
  return <View style={styles.egg} />;
};

StyleSheet.create({
  egg: {
    width: 126,
    height: 180,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    borderTopLeftRadius: 108,
    borderTopRightRadius: 108,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 95,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 95,
  },
});
```

https://codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native